# How to dynamically set path in Thymeleaf fragments?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have the following Thymeleaf snippet

```php-template
<th:block th:replace="~{'/login/' + ${loginBanner} :: ${loginBanner}}"></th:block>
```

In the controller I set `loginBanner` to

```java
model.addAttribute("loginBanner", "login-banner-unauthorized");
```

The `login-banner-unauthorized` fragment is located in `src/main/resources/templates/login/login-banner-unauthorized.html`

I get the following error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [/login/login-banner-unauthorized], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "index" - line 23, col 19)
```

While running the application from InteliJ, everything works but when I deploy jar to cloud I get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed the issue

```php-template
<th:block th:replace="~{'login/'+${loginBanner} :: ${loginBanner}}"></th:block>
```

Notice the forward slash before `login` removed